# react native navigation performance

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I have the Issue with React Native Navigation V2 that there is quite a long waiting time until I can view the next screen.

And I read that it seems to be normal, since react native has to render all components of the new Screen.

So I was wondering if there are certain patterns for better performance 
or ways to hide the loading time (through loading circles or transitions)?

Comment: Use [InteractionManager](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/interactionmanager)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It usually happens if you have a lot of components to render.
React navigation waits for component to mount and then switches to the screen.
For example, If a screen will take 2 seconds to render all the components. Then react navigation will take 2 seconds to switch to that screen.
There is a way you can lower the time to switch to the next screen.
You can use `intreractionManager` or You can do something like,

First keep your state, let's say `loading` to true. And in your `componentDidMount()` You can write something like:

```
setTimeout(() => this.setState({ loading: false }), 0);
```

And in your render function, in your parent view, do a conditional render,
Like

```
{this.state.loading && <View> 
... your components
</View>}
```

With this approach. The component will mount fast as `componentDidMount()` will resolve fast as the component has nothing to render.
Also if you are using `flatlist` or `listview`, you can give the prop `initialRender` to 3 or something like that to decrease loading time.
So. initially render only a single empty view and after that render everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the Suggestion of @Wainage I used InteractionManager

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React from "react";
import {
    InteractionManager,
    Text,
   View,
} from "react-native";

interface State {
   ready: boolean;
   sortedJobs: any[];
}


export default class ProviderJobs extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
          ready: false,
       };
    }

   public componentDidMount() {
       InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
           // Do expensive Stuff such as loading
           this.setState({
               ready: true,
               sortedJobs: groupJobs(this.props.jobs), // loading Jobs in my Case
        });

    });
}

   public render() {
       if (!this.state.ready || this.state.sortedJobs.length == 0) {
           return <LoadingCircle/>;
       }


       return (
           <View>
               <DisplayJobs jobs ={this.state.sortedJobs}>
           </View>
       );
   }
}
```